# Any quick way of updating a column based on timestamp

Tags: mysql

I having a DB table with a column storing time stamp in the following format
01-SEP-2020
I have added a new column BHAV_ID in the same table, with integer datatype,now its blank

Now, I am trying to update the column BHAV_ID based on timestamp value
For example, attached is the screen shot

[image]
19th January 2018 is equivalent to 2180119(YYYYMMDD) updating as integer datatype in that column

I am doing in a dirty technique from java code perspective, where I am reading one row at a time and calculating and updating the value in BHAV_ID column. But its going to take a lot of time.
To update 780records, it took near to 40 min to complete.

There are 20,000,000 records in the table. If I go with Coding appoach, then its going to weeks together, So I am looking for any help in database query level.

Comment: Don't store dates as integers (unless you are storing epoch seconds).  Instead, always use a proper `DATE` or `DATETIME` column.

Comment: TIME_STAMP I am storing as DATETIME, but BHAV_ID is stored as Integer..I thought its just number after the conversion

Comment: According to your screenshot, your `TIME_STAMP` column datatype is not `DATETIME`. If it is, the date (+time) should look like this `yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss` e.g. `2018-01-19 12:59:30`

Comment: you are right, its String datattype.. got confirmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your TIME_STAMP column is a string, then you can use `SUBSTRING` to extract its parts, `CONCAT` to chain them together, and `CAST` to turn that into an integer. The awkward part will be giving MySQL a lookup table to turn the month into an integer:

```sql
UPDATE tableName SET BHAV_ID = CAST(CONCAT(
  SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 8, 4),
  IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'JAN', '01',
     IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'FEB', '02',
     IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'MAR', '03',
     IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'APR', '04',
     IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'MAY', '05',
     IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'JUN', '06',
     IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'JUL', '07',
     IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'AUG', '08',
     IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'SEP', '09',
     IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'OCT', '10',
     IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'NOV', '11',
     IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'DEC', '12', '00')))))))))))),
  SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 1, 2)
) AS UNSIGNED)
WHERE BHAV_ID IS NULL
```

And that seems to work ok:

```
mysql> desc makeItSo;
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| BHAV_ID    | int(8) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TIME_STAMP | varchar(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from makeItSo;
+---------+-------------+
| BHAV_ID | TIME_STAMP  |
+---------+-------------+
|    NULL | 19-JAN-2018 |
|    NULL | 22-JAN-2018 |
|    NULL | 08-MAR-2019 |
|    NULL | 22-MAR-1973 |
|    NULL | 04-JUL-1776 |
|    NULL | 09-DEC-1941 |
|    NULL | 11-NOV-1918 |
|    NULL | 20-JUL-1969 |
|    NULL | 22-NOV-1963 |
+---------+-------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE makeItSo SET BHAV_ID = CAST(CONCAT(
    ->   SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 8, 4),
    ->   IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'JAN', '01',
    ->      IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'FEB', '02',
    ->      IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'MAR', '03',
    ->      IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'APR', '04',
    ->      IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'MAY', '05',
    ->      IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'JUN', '06',
    ->      IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'JUL', '07',
    ->      IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'AUG', '08',
    ->      IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'SEP', '09',
    ->      IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'OCT', '10',
    ->      IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'NOV', '11',
    ->      IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'DEC', '12', '00')))))))))))),
    ->   SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 1, 2)
    -> ) AS UNSIGNED)
    -> WHERE BHAV_ID IS NULL;
Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 9  Changed: 9  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from makeItSo;
+----------+-------------+
| BHAV_ID  | TIME_STAMP  |
+----------+-------------+
| 20180119 | 19-JAN-2018 |
| 20180122 | 22-JAN-2018 |
| 20190308 | 08-MAR-2019 |
| 19730322 | 22-MAR-1973 |
| 17760704 | 04-JUL-1776 |
| 19411209 | 09-DEC-1941 |
| 19181111 | 11-NOV-1918 |
| 19690720 | 20-JUL-1969 |
| 19631122 | 22-NOV-1963 |
+----------+-------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from makeItSo order by BHAV_ID;
+----------+-------------+
| BHAV_ID  | TIME_STAMP  |
+----------+-------------+
| 17760704 | 04-JUL-1776 |
| 19181111 | 11-NOV-1918 |
| 19411209 | 09-DEC-1941 |
| 19631122 | 22-NOV-1963 |
| 19690720 | 20-JUL-1969 |
| 19730322 | 22-MAR-1973 |
| 20180119 | 19-JAN-2018 |
| 20180122 | 22-JAN-2018 |
| 20190308 | 08-MAR-2019 |
+----------+-------------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from makeItSo WHERE BHAV_ID > 20000000 order by BHAV_ID;
+----------+-------------+
| BHAV_ID  | TIME_STAMP  |
+----------+-------------+
| 20180119 | 19-JAN-2018 |
| 20180122 | 22-JAN-2018 |
| 20190308 | 08-MAR-2019 |
+----------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

---

If it's already a `DATETIME` though then you can just use `EXTRACT` to grab each part of it:

```
UPDATE tableName SET BHAV_ID = CAST(
  CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM TIME_STAMP), EXTRACT(DAY FROM TIME_STAMP)
  AS UNSIGNED)
WHERE BHAV_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: First Query is throwing an syntax error, 1st query may works for me.. please help me to complete Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '),      IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP, 4, 3) = 'FEB', '02'),      IF(SUBSTRING(TIME_ST' at line 3

Comment: Sorry I think the edited version above might be better, parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to test it, but something like this?

```
update table as t1,
(
select yourTimeStamp2IntFunction(TIME_STAMP) as intFld from table where TIME_STAMP = t1.TIME_STAMP) as t2
set t1.BHAV_ID = t2.intFld
where t1.BHAV_ID is null
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking like that, but we can write the functions in Query right?

Comment: @gmhk absolutely. Use CONCAT and EXTRACT like in the answer of Jeremy Jones

Answer (score 0):

Provided that all `TIME_STAMP` values are consistent with the format in your example 'DD-MMM-YYYY' and the month are according to the standard abbreviation in MySQL, you can use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) then choose between using [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to generate the format you wanted or simply remove the hyphen (`-`) using [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html).

```
/*USING DATE_FORMAT  + STR_TO_DATE*/
SELECT BHAV_ID, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(TIME_STAMP, '%d-%b-%Y'),'%Y%m%d') 
FROM TABLE_A;

/*USING REPLACE + STR_TO_DATE*/
SELECT BHAV_ID, REPLACE(STR_TO_DATE(TIME_STAMP, '%d-%b-%Y'),'-','') 
FROM TABLE_A;
```

Both query above can transform the current `TIME_STAMP` format that you have to the desired format you wanted. Turn any of this into an `UPDATE` syntax like (taking the first example):

```
UPDATE TABLE_A 
SET BHAV_ID = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(TIME_STAMP, '%d-%b-%Y'),'%Y%m%d') 
WHERE BHAV_ID IS NULL;
```

You can see the [demo fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a9770986d47987ed17a9207be0bd15cf) along with the extracted list of abbreviated month name in MySQL.